# I need to convert this JSON string. Swap single to double quotes and vice versa

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, converters

I am using JSON.stringify to produce the following JSON string from an object:

```
"[{\"text\":\"AA\"},{\"text\":\"B'B\"},{\"text\":\"C\\\"C\"}]"
```

But, the system I need to send this string to requires it to be in this format:

```
'[{"text":"AA"},{"text":"B\'B"},{"text":"C\\"C"}]'
```

This is some other kind of JSON (technically not real JSON). I need some kind of replace function that can convert this properly.

Comment: Why does it matter? Those are equivalent.

Comment: It matters because with a large complex string. the latter will be quite shorter

Comment: Yes, but the escaping is just something that shows up when you want to represent the string **as a string** in JavaScript code. If you assign either of those to a variable and then send it as a payload in a `fetch`, or write them as `innerHTML` to a DOM element or pretty much anything, there won't be any escaping at all. It will just send the raw string value, which would look like `[{"text":"AA"},...]`. (Well you'd still have the escape in the `"C\"C"`, but all the other escaping wouldn't be there, including the `B\'B`)

Answer (score 0):

This should switch the escaping on the strings

```js
let str1 = `"[{\"text\":\"AA\"},{\"text\":\"B'B\"},{\"text\":\"C\\\"C\"}]"`
let str2  = `'[{"text":"AA"},{"text":"B\'B"},{"text":"C\\"C"}]'`

function convertQuotes(str) {
    // unescape double quotes
    str = str.replace(`\"`,'"');
    // escape single quotes
    str = str.replace("'",`\'`);
    // replace start and end
    str = "'"+str.slice(1,str.length-1)+"'";
    return str;
}

console.log(convertQuotes(str1))
console.log(str2);
console.log(convertQuotes(str1)==str2);
```

Comment: This didn't work. I got this when i converted it: '[{\"text\":\"AA\"},{\"text\":\"B'B\"},{\"text\":\"C\\\"C\"}]' . But I think I solved it myself. Will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

These functions seem to solve my problem But is there a better way? I really don't know a great deal about regex syntax.

```
function jsonConvert(str) {
    var newStr=str.substr(1, str.length-2);
    newStr=replaceAll('\\\\"', 'DOUBLE_QUOTE_PLACEHOLDER', newStr);
    newStr=replaceAll('\\"', '\"', newStr);
    newStr = newStr.replace(/([^\{|:|,])(?:')([^\}|,|:])/g, "$1\\'$2");
    newStr=replaceAll('DOUBLE_QUOTE_PLACEHOLDER', "\\\"", newStr)
    return "'"+newStr+"'";
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, str){
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'), replace);
}
```